# 常用于词典里的用于分项列举的各项之间的分号有什么意义？它的意义是“和”、“或”还是“和或者或”？

Tags: grammar

《中华人民共和国国家标准》的“标点符号用法”一章（链接：http://www.moe.gov.cn/ewebeditor/uploadfile/2015/01/13/20150113091548267.pdf ）讲述着汉语中的各种标点符号是怎么正确地使用的。其中，有分号（“；”），八页里就开始解释分号的几种用法。第九页靠上面的地方有这段关于该符号的第三种用法的文字：

*4.6.3.3 用于分项列举的各项之间。*

*示例：特聘教授的岗位职责为：一、讲授本学科的主干基础课程；二、主持本学科的重大科研项目；三、领导本学科的学术队伍建设；四、带领本学科赶超或保持世界先进水平。*

据我观察，词典里的词语释义中的分号，很多是这种用法。要是我没错，这种用于列举中的分号到底有什么意义呢？

举例：《汉语大词典》的“失误”一词条里有以下定义：“差错；过错。”。请问，这里的“差错；过错。”的意思是“差错和过错。”、“差错或过错。”还是“差错和或者或过错。”？词典里的那些数不胜数的具有类似句法的词语释义中的分号起着什么意义上的作用呢？

主要问题并不在于“失误”一词本身，而在于分号在词典里的用法。

（我知道本问题非常微妙，本论坛使用者大多数应该对这种事毫不感兴趣，争奈没有大陆手机号的人在知乎等网站上发问不了？我也试过贴吧，因为贴吧并没有绑定大陆手机号的需求，但那边的回答质量实在很差！）

谢谢。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

在你给出的文档2.1部分有个注解：

> 数学符号、货币符号、校勘符号、**辞书符号**、注音符号等特殊领域的专门符号不属于标点符号

查阅《辞书编纂符号 GB/T 11617-2000》：

5.1.11 分号：同义词群间隔号 separator of synonym groups 置于释文中同义词群之间

结论：这应该属于分号的特殊用法

Answer (score 0):

1. My understanding is that the semi-colon is to be used when separating two or multiple individual components, or complimenting elements, of the subject. Any one of these components can follow the subject to form a complete sentence. For the first example:

- 特聘教授的岗位职责为讲授本学科的主干基础课程.
- 特聘教授的岗位职责为主持本学科的重大科研项目.
- 特聘教授的岗位职责为领导本学科的学术队伍建设.
- 特聘教授的岗位职责为带领本学科赶超或保持世界先进水平.

2. Each of the supplementing elements in example 2 has complete meaning by itself, thus, they should be separated by a semi-colon, otherwise, they shall be connected by "及" or "和", to mean they mean both.

- 《汉语大词典》的“失误”一词条里有以下定义：“差错；过错" = “差错及过错" = “差错和过错".

Answer (score 0):

个人理解
你确实可以把"分号"简单理解为"和"。在你的例子里，它的意义就是分割且连接词项，和逗号类似，也完全可以用逗号代替，算是常见于词典里的一种特殊用法（不在词典里的话，你看到的就该是"差错，过错"这样了）。

更多的，其实可以把分号当作是对逗号的一种补充。

> 词典里当作"和"完全没问题，比如：
> abdominous 大肚子的，大腹便便的；肥胖的。分号在起到逗号的作用时，更体现一种区分的作用
> 大肚子的，大腹便便的，肥胖的。这种就没有区分。
> 大肚子的，大腹便便的。这种逗号已经足够分割连接词条的同义解释（所以这种"差错；过错"特殊）。
> 大肚子的；大腹便便的。感觉也不错。
> 大腹便便的；肥胖的。用于区分更常见。

分号主要还是用在句子中，来补充体现成分的并列，选择，承接，转折，递进等关系。

Answer (score -1):

; 的意义大概相当于"或"的意思。

所以，"失误"一词要么是"差错", 要么是"过错". 具体意思要根据用法和上下文来判断。